# How to continue the process in another class after the AsyncTask finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm working on a project and i have a question about the AsyncTask. 
What i'm trying to do is to separate the AsyncTask from my classes, by writing it once and call it from any class. 
So I have created a class named A that is a fragment activity and contains a list view. In this class i'm creating an object of the AsyncTask to get data from the xml and create a list with this data. When the AsyncTask finished i want to send this list back to the class A and continue the process by adding the list in the list view and update the layout. 
What i have to do in the onPostExecute to past the data in the class A and how i can make the class to know about the process of the AsyncTask so it can continue? 
Thanks

Here is a simple of my code in which i'm creating the object of the AsyncTask.

```
GetXMLData load = new GetXMLData();
if (this.count == 1)
{
  load.Set_URL(XML_URL);
  this.count++;
}
else
{
  load.Set_URL(XML_URL, "?paged=" + this.count);
  this.count++;
}
LinkedList<Contents> content_list;
load.start_LoadContents();
this.list = new ArrayList<Contents>();
content_list = load.get_XML_List();
Log.i("content_list", "The content_list is " + content_list.size());
```

Comment: you can use broadcast receiver, send broadcast after finishing `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TaskListener {

TaskListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listener = this;
    new BackgroundTask(listener).execute("");

}

@Override
public void taskComplete(ArrayList<String> list) {
    if (list.size() != 0) {
        Log.i("Log", "list  " + list.get(0));
    }
}

}
```

TaskListener.java

```
public interface TaskListener {
    public void taskComplete(ArrayList<String> list);
}
```

BackgroundTask.java

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

TaskListener listner;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public BackgroundTask(TaskListener l) {
    this.listner = l;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // do your background task like below
    list.add("Android");
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    listner.taskComplete(list);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it can be solved with the Observer pattern.

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> implements MySubjectInterface {

List<Observer> observerl = new ArrayList<Observer>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // do your background task like below
    list.add("Android");
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    notifyObservers();

}

/**
 * Observer pattern, this allows to register for changes.
 */
@Override
public void register(Observer obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Null Observer");
    if (!observerl.contains(obj))
        observerl.add(obj);
}

/**
 * Observer pattern, this allows to unregister for changes.
 */
@Override
public void unregister(Observer obj) {
    observerl.remove(obj);
}

/**
 * Notifies the observers.
 */
@Override
public synchronized void notifyObservers() {
    for (Observer obj : observerl)
        obj.update();
}

}
```

Then you can register your Activity which implements your Observer to the Asynctask.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Anyway from my own experiences, this is easiest solved by making a class which controls all the data. It should show "old" data from your sqllite or some information you parsed earlier and show that on create. This will solve problems in the future when the xml file cant be found or if there is no connection to the internet. The app can still be used, but just not with the newest data (which you should notify the user on). Then when the View is shown new data is received in the background and loaded/parsed and saved in your class that holds the information. Then you send a notification back to your activity that new data is ready to be shown in for example your ListView. And ofcourse to for loose-coupling observer pattern is important here.

This way your application isn't waiting for long operations (web requests, parsing xml/json).